# How to check the validation of Google Maps Android API v1 key?

Tags: android, google-maps

I developed a maps application using Android Google Maps API v1 an year ago. I used debug key for testing and it worked.

1. My question is how long the API key works? Is there a way to check that?
2. Does my application crash due if the key expires?
3. I also saw that Google Maps API v1 is depreciated and no longer keys are generated. So does the code developed in v1 work now if the key is still valid?

Comment: as i heard mapv1 was'nt supported anymore :(

Comment: cant you just debug the app and see where its crashing

Comment: @tyczj I just tried to debug and found the reason why it crashes. It crashes due to gps disabled on the mobile.

Comment: well there you go, it has nothing to do with google maps key then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how long the api key works?

Until Google discontinues support for Maps V1. There is no published timetable for this. However, I'd move to Maps V2 or some other alternative soonish.

> Does my application crash due if the key expires?

The API key will not "expire" until the underlying signing key does. If for some reason this would happen before Maps V1 is shut down, I have no idea what would happen.

> So does the code developed in v1 work now if the key is still valid?

Yes, until Google discontinues support for Maps V1.